# Change background property of grid dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a `TextBox` and wanted to know how I can change my `Grid.Background` property dynamically when user enters the hex code and clicks the button.

```
colorPlace.SetValue(BackgroundProperty, "#FFFFFFFF");

borderColor.Background = GetColor("#75ED13");
```

did not understand the `GetColor` is a method from which class

```
LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(txtrgb.Text);
```

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Media.Color'

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523248/how-do-i-convert-a-string-color-to-a-brush-in-winrt

Comment: @dkozl tried the code on the link u mentioned gives me an error colorhelper does not exist in current context

Comment: copy `ColorToBrush` method from not accepted answer and do something like `LayoutRoot.Background = ColorToBrush(txtrgb.Text)`

Comment: no no what i mean is that colorhelper is not defined as a class/object/method ie compiler is not able to understand where colorhelper is defined.I added windows.ui but not able to add windows.ui.xaml.media

Comment: Got it Working

LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, Convert.ToByte(txtrgb.Text.Substring(1, 2), 16), Convert.ToByte(txtrgb.Text.Substring(3, 2), 16), Convert.ToByte(txtrgb.Text.Substring(5, 2), 16)));

LayoutRoot is my Grid View Name

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class ColorsHelper
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, Color> dict =
              typeof(Colors).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
              .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
              .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => (Color)prop.GetValue(null, null));

        public static Color FromName(string name)
        {
            return dict[name];
        }
    }

textBox1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(ColorsHelper.FromName(txtrgb.Text));
```

Code taken from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257780/getting-solidcolorbrush-from-a-string)